# How to compare dates in Fullcalendar plugin with an array of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want to compare a set of days in an array with all the dates in the calendar.
This is my code what I have written. How should I pass the array to dayrender function?

### Method for getting the dates

```
function GetFoodDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Food/getFoodDetails',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            myArray = new Array(result.length);
            for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                debugger;
                //  myArray[index] = Date(result[index].Date.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].toString());
                var date = new Date(parseInt(result[index].Date.substr(6)));
                myArray[index] = date;                    

            } //end of loop
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('eror');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });        
}
```

### in Fullcalendar plugin

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    myArray.forEach(function (item) {
        if (date._d.getDate() == item.getDate() && date._d.getMonth() == item.getMonth()) 
        {
            $(cell).toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Husen how should i get the array in Dayrender function. It is undefined there..

Answer (score 1):

Well, jquery [Data Method](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/data-methods/) can help you here:

Add, `$('body').data( "date_global", myArray);` to store your date array.

You can try this technique like:

```
function GetFoodDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Food/getFoodDetails',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            myArray = new Array(result.length);
            for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                debugger;
                //  myArray[index] = Date(result[index].Date.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].toString());
                var date = new Date(parseInt(result[index].Date.substr(6)));
                myArray[index] = date;                    

            } //end of loop
            $('body').data( "date_global", myArray);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('eror');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });        
}
```

For, fetching this array anywhere in the code write: `$('body').data( "date_global" )`

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    console.log($('body').data( "date_global" ));
    myArray.forEach(function (item) {
        if (date._d.getDate() == item.getDate() && date._d.getMonth() == item.getMonth()) 
        {
            $(cell).toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });
}
```